# Compress multiple blob Excel files into a zip file javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, zip, blob

I am actually using this library: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.
I used it to create and download an XLSX file that extracts a table from my website. This does work pretty well, but I am trying to do something more complicated now.

I am trying to download all my tables at the same time, which means downloading multiple XLSX files. It does works with my actual code :

```
function saveAll(dataAll){
    for (let i=0;i<dataAll.length;++i) {
        let ws_name = "SheetJS";
        let data = dataAll[i];

        let wb = new Workbook();
        console.log(data);
        let ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data.content, null, data.mois, data.annee);

        /* add worksheet to workbook */
        wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
        wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;

        let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary'});

        saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type: "application/octet-stream"}), data.prenom_nom + " PVA " + data.mois + " " + data.annee + ".xlsx");
    }
}
```

Now i'd like to download all those xlsx files into an unique ZIP or tar.gz file, but i am kinda stuck. I tryed to use the zip.js library, but without success.

My dataAll parameter is array of objects, and each object contains .content which is a matrix, and some other parameters used on the file name.

How can I manage to download all these xlsx files in only one archive, instead of downloading them one by one?

Comment: PS, if you run in to any constraints with many or larger files, take a look at this streaming solution: [saving multiple files](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/examples/saving-multiple-files.html) with [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
for(var i=1;i<3;i++)
{
    var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('tbl'+i));
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws1, "Sheet1");
    let wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary'});
    
    zip.file("shubham"+i+".xlsx", wbout, {binary: true});
}
    
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    // see FileSaver.js
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1, shrink>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <title>ES6</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="tbl1">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Shubham</td><td>22</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="tbl2">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Shubham</td><td>22</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It didn't worked when i tryed because my scripts imports were in the wrong order, because xlsx.js is using an outdated version of jszip.